# When overloading bounded generics, how can I return the right type?

Tags: java, generics

The following code gives a compilation error. How coud I avoid this?

```
public class C<T> {

    public T doStuff(T arg) {}

}

public class S<T extends Number> extends C<T> {

    public T doStuff(T arg) {
        return new Integer(0);
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this declaration is illegal because, while you've said that `T` is *some* kind of `Number`, there's no way to specifically mandate that `T` is *specifically* an `Integer` at all times.

```
public T doStuff(T arg) {
    return new Integer(0);
}
```

That `T` may very well be a `Long` or a `Float` or a `BigInteger`, none of which are `Integer`.

Luckily, `Number` has the `intValue()` method, which allows you to get an int from any of those `Number` types.  You can use that instead:

```
public Integer doStuff(T arg) {
    return new Integer(arg.intValue());
}
```

You *are* going to have to change the way your `doStuff` method works in the parent class, though; introduce a new type parameter to the method.

```
public <S> S doStuff(S arg) {
    return arg;
}
```

Of course, this means now that the `doStuff` method is unbound as well.  If you really wanted to keep the bounds on `Number` for the entire class, you would have to have your class use the actual concrete type you cared about.

```
class S extends C<Integer> {
    public Integer doStuff(Integer arg) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That gives me a different error, because my return type is no longer compatible with the generic method in C<T>.

Comment: I caught that, and have submitted an edit for it.  Check it now.

Comment: @Makoto If the OP changes the signature of the doStuff method in class C, what's the purpose of the type parameter T in class C?

Comment: So if I understand, there's no way around this without implementing a separate method / class for each concrete `Number` type (`Integer`, `Double`, ...)? Or as least as many `Number` types as I want to use the class with?

Comment: In all honesty, there *wouldn't* be any reason to have it anymore.  Hence, the suggestion for another approach - binding it to the class they actually care about.

Comment: @tb189:  Generics are really meant to work with the generic type.  If you want to work with the concrete type, you have to provide it.